# postgresql display products that were ordered

Tags: postgresql

i havе tables like this and i need to display products that were ordered

```sql
create table customer ( 
   id                   int                  primary key, 
   first_name           varchar(100)         not null, 
   last_name            varchar(100)         not null,
   city                 varchar(100)         null,
   country              varchar(100)         null,
   phone                varchar(100)         null

);

create table supplier (
   id                    int                  primary key,
   company_name          varchar(100)         not null,
   contact_name          varchar(100)         null,
   contact_title         varchar(100)         null,
   city                  varchar(100)         null,
   country               varchar(100)         null,
   phone                 varchar(100)         null,
   fax                   varchar(100)         null
);

create table product (
   id                    int                  primary key,
   product_name          varchar(100)         not null,
   unit_price            decimal(12,2)        null default 0,
   package               varchar(100)         null,
   is_discontinued       boolean              not null default false,
   supplier_id           int                  references supplier(id) not null
);

create table orders (
   id                    int                  primary key,
   order_date            timestamp            not null default now(),
   order_number          varchar(100)         null,
   total_amount          decimal(12,2)        null default 0,
   customer_id           int                  references customer(id) not null
);

create table order_item (
   id                    int                  primary key,
   unit_price            decimal(12,2)        not null default 0,
   quantity              int                  not null default 1,
   order_id              int                  references orders(id) not null,
   product_id            int                  references product(id) not null
);
```

Comment: Tip: Consider using `VARCHAR(255)` as a default general-purpose string-type field and only override this with longer or shorter constraints if you have a compelling reason. Many MySQL installations will silently truncate any data which doesn’t fit, resulting in lost data, user complaints, and other serious issues. Names and email addresses are quite frequently surprisingly long, so accommodating these is important.

Comment: Do you want distinct products that were ordered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need `product_name` of products that were ordered, you can do the below sql. It involves only 2 tables.

```
select distinct p.product_name
from order_item o
join product p
on o.product_id = p.id
```

[Postgres DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c9ac2f395a382b59947b12ec6d942b68)

Comment: thank you)) can you help me pls, now i need to display products that weren't ordered

Comment: Use `except` clause between this table and `product` table.